# A possibly-terrible alternative to conditionals full of null checks

Tags: c#, null, properties

I am always super annoyed when I have to write a bunch of `if` statements whenever I have to traverse an object graph of possibly null objects. As there is not yet a `?.` operator I resorted to creating this wonderful piece of work: `TryGetProperty`. Please tear it apart. This was written for LINQPad.

```
public bool TryGetProperty<TInstance, TFinal>(TInstance instance, Expression<Func<TInstance, TFinal>> propertyAccessor, out TFinal output)
{

    var currentExpression = propertyAccessor.Body as MemberExpression;
    var stack = new Stack<PropertyInfo>();
    do
    {
       stack.Push(currentExpression.Member as PropertyInfo);
    } while((currentExpression = currentExpression.Expression as MemberExpression) != null);

    var failed = false;

    object currentObject = instance;
    while(!failed && stack.Count > 0 )
    {
        currentObject = stack.Pop().GetMethod.Invoke(currentObject, null);
        failed = currentObject == null && stack.Count != 0;
    }

    output = failed ? default(TFinal) : (TFinal) currentObject;
    return !failed;
}
```

---

Example call from the same file.

> ```
> void Main()
> {  
>     List<Class1> instances = new List<Class1> 
>     {
>         new Class1(),
>         new Class1
>         {
>             Class2 = new Class2
>             {
>                 Class3 = new Class3
>                 {
>                     AProperty = "not null"
>                 }
>             }
>         },
>         new Class1
>         {
>             Class2 = new Class2
>             {
>                 Class3 = new Class3()
>             }
>         }
>     };
>
>     string propertyToGet;
>
>     foreach(var instance in instances) 
>     {
>        if(TryGetProperty(instance, c => c.Class2.Class3.AProperty, out propertyToGet) && propertyToGet != null)
>        {
>             "Yay!".Dump();
>        }
>        else
>        {
>             "Boo!".Dump();
>        }
>     }
> }
>
> public class Class1
> {
>     public Class2 Class2{ get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Class2
> {
>     public Class3 Class3 { get; set; }
> }
> public class Class3
> {
>     public string AProperty { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Comment: There is a `?.` operator for C# 6.0. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> public bool TryGetProperty<TInstance, TFinal>(TInstance instance, Expression<Func<TInstance, TFinal>> propertyAccessor, out TFinal output)
> {
>
>     var currentExpression = propertyAccessor.Body as MemberExpression;
>     var stack = new Stack<PropertyInfo>();
>     do
>     {
>        stack.Push(currentExpression.Member as PropertyInfo);
>     } while((currentExpression = currentExpression.Expression as MemberExpression) != null);
>
>     var failed = false;
>
>     object currentObject = instance;
>     while(!failed && stack.Count > 0 )
>     {
>         currentObject = stack.Pop().GetMethod.Invoke(currentObject, null);
>         failed = currentObject == null && stack.Count != 0;
>     }
>
>     output = failed ? default(TFinal) : (TFinal) currentObject;
>     return !failed;
> }
> ```

This will throw an `ArgumentNullException` at `var currentExpression = propertyAccessor.Body as MemberExpression;` if `propertyAccessor` is `null`.

It will also throw the same exception if `propertyAccessor.Body != MemberExpression` because you are accessing the `Member` property here `stack.Push(currentExpression.Member as PropertyInfo);`.

If you use the `as` soft cast, you should always check the result against `null`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the thing shouldn't be very forgiving if you abused it. I could do some preemptive checking though

Answer (score 8):

I tend to use monads in such situations:

```
public static TResult With<TSource, TResult>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> action)
    where TSource : class
{
    if (source == null) return default(TResult);
    return action(source);
}

public static TSource Do<TSource>(this TSource source, Action<TSource> action)
    where TSource : class
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        action(source);
    }
    return source;
}
```

And then:

```
c.With(x => x.Class2).With(x => x.Class3).With(x => x.AProperty).Do(x => "Yay!".Dump());
```

Comment: I like `With` if it's on a builder class and not an extension on every reference type. However, I think I could do without `Do`. In order to make your code behave the same as my code using `Do`, you'd have to resort to continuation-passing, e.g. `(TSource source, Action<TSource> success, Action<TSource> failed)`. So I guess it depends on whether your context demands a functional approach or not.

Comment: @moarboilerplate Or, you could write something like an `ElseDo` method that calls the `Action` on the inverse condition, rather than having to add responsibility to `Do`.

Comment: A state monad need only be responsible for the state and the result of evaluating the state (i.e. the actual property value). It would be far simpler to have the final method just return the actual value instead of also having it executing delegates based on evaluating the evaluation of the state.

Comment: (and writing ElseDo would still be passing continuations, just in separate methods)